# Same cookie gets set at different localhost origins

Tags: php, http, cookies, same-origin-policy

I've two PHP apps one on `localhost:8080` (vuln) and the other on `localhost:42069` (attacker).

`8080` has a login page, which on login saves a cookie.

`42069` sets no cookies (has no PHP code) and only has an HTML form that logs the user out of `8080` using a logout POST request.

When I log `document.cookie` at `42069` after logging into `8080` I get to see the same cookie as `8080`.

What's going on here?

App sources [repo](https://github.com/AvirukBasak/php-csrf). Run the app with `start.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both sites have the same domain `localhost`. Your Browser stores cookies for each domain which is determined by the part after the protocol(`http`, `https`) and before the first `/`. In your case `localhost:8080` and `localhost:42069` are considered to be the same domain. Cookies set by on page will be available to the other page as well.

This behavior is defined in [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

> 1.Introduction
>
> [...]
>
> For historical reasons, cookies contain a number of security and privacy infelicities.  For example, a server can
> indicate that a given cookie is intended for "secure" connections, but
> the Secure attribute does not provide integrity in the presence of an
> active network attacker.  **Similarly, cookies for a given host are
> shared across all the ports on that host, even though the usual
> "same-origin policy" used by web browsers isolates content retrieved
> via different ports.**

And

> 8.5.  Weak Confidentiality
>
> **Cookies do not provide isolation by port.**  If a cookie is readable by a service running on one port, the cookie is also readable by a
> service running on another port of the same server.

If you want the two apps to have separate cookies you could try to use subdomains or different top-level domains: E.g. `app1.localhost:8080` and `app2.localhost:42069`. This may cause the browser to store the cookies separatly.

Note this is not guaranteed to work see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-8.6)

> 8.6.  Weak Integrity
>
> Cookies do not provide integrity guarantees for sibling domains (and their subdomains).  For example, consider
> foo.example.com and bar.example.com.  The foo.example.com server can
> set a cookie with a Domain attribute of "example.com" (possibly
> overwriting an existing "example.com" cookie set by bar.example.com),
> and the user agent will include that cookie in HTTP requests to
> bar.example.com.  In the worst case, bar.example.com will be unable to
> distinguish this cookie from a cookie it set itself.  The
> foo.example.com server might be able to leverage this ability to mount
> an attack against bar.example.com.

### Guaranteed Solution

**You can run one page on `localhost` and the other on `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.2`, etc.** Because these are two different domains. Means a cookie on `localhost` cannot be shared with `127.0.0.x` and vice versa.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! ( which php > /dev/null ); then
    echo 'error: php not installed'
    exit 1
fi

php -S localhost:8080 --docroot=website-vuln/public/ 2>> vuln.log >> vuln.log &
php -S 127.0.0.1:42069 --docroot=website-evil/public/ 2>> evil.log >> evil.log &

echo vuln server @ http://localhost:8080
echo evil server @ http://127.0.0.1:42069
```

On Linux `/etc/hosts` can be used to create more cookie domains for `127.0.0.1` than `localhost`. And as many meaningfull names for `127.0.0.x`

E.g.
/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    app1
127.0.0.1    app2
```

Then you can modify your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! ( which php > /dev/null ); then
    echo 'error: php not installed'
    exit 1
fi

php -S app1:8080 --docroot=website-vuln/public/ 2>> vuln.log >> vuln.log &
php -S app2:42069 --docroot=website-evil/public/ 2>> evil.log >> evil.log &

echo vuln server @ http://app1:8080
echo evil server @ http://app2:42069
```

Now you have to change the link in your form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://app1:8080/">
```

In Windows 10 the hosts file is located at `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.